# Where are blazegraph data files located? Can they be deleted to fix undeletable namespace?

Tags: delete-file, blazegraph

Somehow we have a namespace that is corrupted and cannot be deleted using the webpage for namespaces (that is about the extent of the message you get...). Where are the blazegraph data files located on disk so I can delete them and restart blazegraph to have them be recreated. I can create and repopulate the namespaces we want... We are running version 2.1.4.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/bigdata/discussion/676946/thread/4ee19941/ might discuss part of your question

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang. I didn't see the reference to the file system location for namespace files so I could remove them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be all inside the `bigdata.jnl` journal file

- if you are using the `.jar` executable, the journal file created in the same folder
- if you are deploying in a container i.e. Tomcat it should be somewhere inside `/etc`, `/opt`, `/usr` or near `CATALINA_HOME`

EDIT: you can find more info about the .jnl file here https://github.com/blazegraph/database/issues/41